# cut string and assign into array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how can I cut a string and then assign into an array with javascript? Example:

var string = "15;24;67;34;56";

I hope tp cut this string into below format and assign into the array:

a[0] = 15
a[1] = 24
a[2] = 67
a[3] = 34
a[3] = 56

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var a = string.split(';');`

Answer (score 0):

string.split(";")

In this example, you'll end up with an extra array item at the end, though, so you'll want to handle that separately.

Comment: No, the string was specified as "15;24;67;34;56"—there would be no extra array item at the end, as far as I am aware. If you're talking about the array indices the OP mentioned, I think that's a typo.